# How to use CakePHP to do a query bounded by data in two indirectly-related tables

Tags: sql, cakephp, join

Presume the Query works:

```
SELECT
    users.id,
    subscriptions.name,
    users.user_type
FROM users
LEFT JOIN users_subscriptions
    ON users.id = users_subscriptions.user_id
LEFT JOIN subscriptions
    ON users_subscriptions.subscription_id = subscriptions.id
WHERE
    subscriptions.name = 'advertisers'
    AND
    users.user_type = 'agent';
```

How do I do this in a single Query using cakePHP 1.3?

EDIT: Are joins the right approach?

Comment: CakePHP joins are described in detail [here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#joining-tables) and [here](http://www.travisbennett.net/1/post/2012/01/manual-joins-using-cakephp-13.html)

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeCummins That will probably be a good stopgap, I'm just sure I'm overlooking a way that cake does this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes joins are just fine. Just make sure that you add on the fly before searching to your User model a `hasOne` to `UsersSubscription` and to the `UsersSubscription` model as belongsTo `Subscription`. Then use the containable behavior to include `'UserSubscription' => 'Susbcription'`

Your code might look like this:

```
$this->User->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('UserSubscription')));
$this->User->UserSubscription->bindModel(array('belongsTo' => array('Subscription')));
$results = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'UserSubscription' => 'Subscription'
    )
));
```

Comment: SO, I already have a HABTM relationship for this, but there doesn't appear to be an effective means to utilize that, to query accross all three tables. This doesn't actually show how to build the query.

Comment: I actually just gave you the query, you just need to add fields and conditions to it.

Comment: oh. I don't know how I over looked that.  I think I must be under-using containable.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the query the "CakePHP way" like this:

```
$conditions = array(
    'Subscriptions.name' => 'advertisers',
    'Users.user_type'    => 'agent'
);

$joins = array(
    array(
        'table'      => 'users_subscriptions',
        'alias'      => 'UsersSubscriptions',
        'type'       => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'UsersSubscriptions.user_id=Users.id'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'table'      => 'subscriptions',
        'alias'      => 'Subscriptions',
        'type'       => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Subscriptions.id=UsersSubscriptions.subscription_id'
        )
    )
);
$fields = array(
    'Users.id', 'Users.user_type', 'Subscriptions.name'
);

$options = array(
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'joins'      => $joins,
    'fields'     => $fields
);

$results = $this->Users->find('all', $options);
```